# Variable in windows function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing some VBA codes for a daily report. In itself, the ActualDate is a variable dimmed as Date. It is changing according to the date of the report and I want to use the input file to implement a few columns. Once I try to activate it once again after changing the window, I am not able to.

My code:

```
Windows("Inputfile" & ActualDate).Activate
```

How should I change the code so command Windows will work with a variable in it? I just need to activate the Excel file called for example Inputfile201021.xlsx. A hint is that at the beginning of the macro, I am used to opening the latest input file. Can I set its name to some constant and use it further in the code?

Comment: You don't need the `windows`-command - just use your workbook-object and activate this. If you really want to use `Windows` then you have to add the fileextension (e.g. .xlsx)

Comment: Updated code:
`Set InputWbook = ActiveWorkbook
 Windows(InputWbook).Activate`

This is giving run-time error 13. Type missmatch. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `InputWbook.activate` is the way

Answer (score 0):

> , I am used to opening the latest input file. Can I set its name to some constant and use it further in the code?

No need to activate the window. You can work with the workbook like this.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim flName As String
    Dim ActualDate As String
    
    ActualDate = "201021"
    
    flName = "Inputfile" & ActualDate
    
    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\" & flName & ".xlsx")
    
    With wb
        '
        '~~> No need to activate. directly work with it here
        '
    End With
End Sub
```